# flutter ios dynamic link always opening appstore, i have associated domain set to applinks:XXXX.XXX correctly,

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working on a flutter project ios app and implementing firebase dynamic links.

I've followed all steps, but now is working. My app always opening to app store, it first opens safari and then app store even when the app is installed.

If someone has a solution to this please help me out, its 3 days now on the same thing and I have not cracked it

1. I have associated domain set to `applinks:domain.page.link`
2. I have even deleted the ios folder and re-created it again
3. I have a URL scheme set to my bundle id

I have followed all steps but still, my apps open.